# How do I exclude images from javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, absolute

I'm trying this thing out in [codepen](https://codepen.io/jjchung13/pen/oNBpOrY),
Here's couple things.

1. I want the blue filler image that appears when hovered over texts to be positioned absolute, staying in the same position while scrolling, but right now it scrolls up with the texts.
2. I want the image to not track the mouse and just stay flat, I was looking up how to bring elements out of parent div but it seems like that's not the solution?

Can anyone help with it please?

```
    <div id="ex1" class="container">
      <div id="ex1-layer" class="box">
        <a id="hero-text" href="#"><img id="hero-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff">LOREM IPSUM!</a>
        <a id="hero-text" href="#"><img id="hero-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff">IS A PLACEHOLDER TEXT</a>
        <a id="hero-text" href="#"><img id="hero-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff">COMMONLY USED</a>
        <a id="hero-text" href="#"><img id="hero-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff">IN THE GRAPHIC,</a>
        <a id="hero-text" href="#"><img id="hero-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff">PRINT, AND PUBLISHING INDUSTRIES</a>
        <a id="hero-text" href="#"><img id="hero-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff">FOR PREVIEWING</a>
        <a id="hero-text" href="#"><img id="hero-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff">LAYOUTS AND</a>
        <a id="hero-text" href="#"><img id="hero-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff">VISUAL MOCKUPS.</a>
    
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
body {
  background: hsla(220, 6%, 12%, 1);
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 75vw;
  top: 12.5vh;
  left: 12.5vw;
  /*border: 2px solid red;*/
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 75vw;
  height: 75vh;
  /*border: 2px solid green;*/
}

#hero-text {
  font-family: roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 6rem;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  flex-direction: reverse;
  /*border: 2px solid blue;*/
}

#hero-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
  width: 20vw;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#hero-text:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }

#hero-text:hover #hero-img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```
let constrain = 300;
let mouseOverContainer = document.getElementById("ex1");
let ex1Layer = document.getElementById("ex1-layer");

function transforms(x, y, el) {
  let box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  let calcX = -(y - box.y - (box.height / 2)) / constrain;
  let calcY = (x - box.x - (box.width / 2)) / constrain;
  
  return "perspective(500px) "
    + "   rotateX("+ calcX +"deg) "
    + "   rotateY("+ calcY +"deg) ";
};

 function transformElement(el, xyEl) {
  el.style.transform  = transforms.apply(null, xyEl);
}

mouseOverContainer.onmousemove = function(e) {
  let xy = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
  let position = xy.concat([ex1Layer]);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    transformElement(ex1Layer, position);
  });
};
```

Comment: You have a lot of duplicated IDs (like "hero-text", "hero-img"), which is not valid for HTML.